# retrieving multiple random rows from MySQL query result set - without using order by rand()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which aims to retrieve a random row from a result set. I do not want to use `ORDER BY Rand()` as it seems to be rather inefficient.

My method is as follows:

- generate a single random number between [0,1)
- give each row of the result query a unique 'rank' number. i.e. give the first row a value 1, second row a value 2, and so forth
- use the random number to get a number between 1 and the number of rows in the result
- return the row where rank == the number generated from the random number

example query:

```
SELECT * FROM(

    (SELECT @rand := RAND(), @rank := 0) r1
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) as num, A.id FROM
    A JOIN B
    ON A.id = B.id
    WHERE B.number = 42
)
WHERE num = FLOOR(1 + @rand * @rank) LIMIT 1
```

This works for retrieving one row, but I instead want 10 random rows. Changing `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 10` doesn't work, because if `num + 10 > number of rows` the query doesn't return 10 rows.

The only solution I can think of it to either generate 10 random numbers in the sql query, check they are all different from each other and have several `WHERE num = random_number_1` lines. Alternatively, I could call the query 10 times, checking that the rows selected are unique. I wouldn't know how to do the former, and the latter seems like it is rather inefficient. Unless there is likely to be some wonderful cache that would make running the same query extremely fast?

Does anyone have any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
select sq2.c1 
  from  ( select * 
            from (select @count :=  0) sq0
           cross join  
                 (select t1.c1, @count := @count+1        
                    from t t1       
                    join t t2      
                   using(c1)      
                   where t2.c2 = 42    
                 ) sq1  
         ) sq2   
 --use a probability to pick random rows
 where if(@count <= 5, 1, floor(1 + rand() * (@count-1))) <= ceiling(log(pow(@count,2)))+1
 limit 5;
```

The results will be random unless the result set is smaller (or the same size as) the limit.  If this is a problem, you can wrap the whole thing:

```
select sq3.* from ( select ... limit 5 ) sq3 
order by rand().
```

This will only randomize the small number of output rows (at most 5) which is efficient.

Of course, you can always use a temporary table:

```
create temporary table rset (row_key int auto_increment, key(row_key))
as ( select .... where c2 = 42 ) engine=myisam;

set @count := select count(*) from rset;

select rset.c1 
  from rset 
 where row_key in (    (floor(1 + rand() * (@count-1))),
(floor(1 + rand() * (@count-1))),
(floor(1 + rand() * (@count-1))),
(floor(1 + rand() * (@count-1))),
(floor(1 + rand() * (@count-1))) );

drop table rset;
```

If you want to guarantee that you get five unique rows, then you can use a second temporary table:

```
create temporary table row_keys ( row_key int not null primary key );
-- do this successful five times.  if you get a unique key error try again
insert into row_keys values (floor(1 + rand() * (@count-1));

select rset.c1
  from rset
  join row_keys
  using(row_key);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what's going on with this line 'where if(@count <= 5, 1, ....', although it does seem to work!. I think the temporary table idea is nice, but how can I be sure of unique rows?

Comment: I think maybe I've figured it out. Assuming there are more than 5 rows, isn't it iterating over each row, creating a random number between 1 and (max_rows -1) and checking whether or not is it less than a value generated by the log & pow functions. If it is less, then it is included into the result set. Does this not rely on the chance that 5 rows manage to pass this check. It also would require a random number to be generated for each row in the result set?

Comment: It does require that 5 rows manage to pass the check.  This method works (and performs) best when there are a large number of results to randomize.  ORDER BY RAND() will only perform well when there are a small number of results to randomize, but it will generate equally random results regardless of result size.  ORDER BY RAND() on a five row resultset will by very fast, but very slow on a 1M row resultset.  My method may not return enough rows when the resultset is small, unless you change <= 5 to be <= 10, that is, 2x the limit and rely on ORDER BY RAND() to sort the small number of results.

Comment: I updated the answer to include how to get N unique rows using the temporary table method.

Comment: Many thanks Justin. I think I will go with the temporary table method actually.